# Observe the progress of the workmanager while it is in the running state

Tags: android, performance

How can I get the progress of a task in workmanager, while the task is running?

```
I have tried it with setProgress(workDataOf(...)), but the final result reaches the activity, when the task ends.
```

Can you help me or guide me please, thank you very much for reading my question.

Version dependecy workmanager:

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.8.0'
```

***doWork() method code block***

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        var intentosInscripcion: Int = 3
        var timer: CountDownTimer
        //var outputData = workDataOf()
        //val minutesTimer: Long = (60 * 1000 * 30)
        val minutesTimer: Long = 50000
        var timeleft: Long = 0
        var formatDate = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"


        try {
            setForeground(getForegroundInfo())


            //correr timer de 30 minutos y consultar servicio para saber si despues del bloqueo responde statusCode http 200
            val inputData =
                inputData.getString(Constants.KEY_REINTENTOS_INSCRIPCION)
            Log.i("inputdata", "inputdata = $inputData")


            val startDateFormat =
                SimpleDateFormat(formatDate, Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
            setProgress(workDataOf(Constants.KEY_TIMER_INSCRIPCION to "///$startDateFormat"))


            delay(3000)
            val endDateFormat =
                SimpleDateFormat(formatDate, Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
            val data = Date()
            setProgress(workDataOf(Constants.KEY_TIMER_INSCRIPCION to "----$endDateFormat"))


            delay(2000)
            val endDateFormat3 =
                SimpleDateFormat(formatDate, Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
            setProgress(workDataOf(Constants.KEY_TIMER_INSCRIPCION to "****$endDateFormat3"))

            Log.i("hora", "start: $startDateFormat :::: end: $endDateFormat  end3:$endDateFormat3")
            Log.i("hora", "data: $data ")


            return Result.success(workDataOf(Constants.KEY_TIMER_INSCRIPCION to "MI HORA FINAL = $endDateFormat3"))

        } catch (th: Throwable) {
            th.printStackTrace()
            return Result.failure(
                workDataOf("ERROR_MSG" to th.localizedMessage)
            )
        }

    }
```

***ViewModel***

```
val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(ExtendedApplication.mContext)
    val oneTimeWorkRequest = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<WorkerActivate>()
        .setConstraints(setConstraints())
        .setInputData(createInputData())
        .addTag(Constants.TAG_OUTPUT)
        .setExpedited(OutOfQuotaPolicy.RUN_AS_NON_EXPEDITED_WORK_REQUEST)
        .setBackoffCriteria(
            BackoffPolicy.LINEAR,
            2000,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .build()

var workInfo= workManager.getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData(Constants.MANIPULATION_WORK_NAME)

///////

workManager.enqueueUniqueWork(
            Constants.MANIPULATION_WORK_NAME,
            ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP,
            oneTimeWorkRequest
        )
```

***Activity***

```
checkoutViewModel.workInfo.observe(this, Observer { item ->

            /*Log.i(
                "data99893df",
                "state workinfo : seguimos trabajando : ${item[0].outputData.getString(KEY_TIMER_INSCRIPCION)}"
            )*/

            if (item.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                return@Observer
            }
            item.forEach {
                var dataInfo = it.outputData.getString(KEY_TIMER_INSCRIPCION)
                Log.i("amar333d", "for EACH **********status = ${it.state}  RESULT = :::::  $dataInfo")
                if (it.state.isFinished) {
                    Log.i("ffsss", "isFinished : status =  ${it.state} ----RESULT = :::::  $dataInfo")
                } else {
                    Log.i("ffsss", "trabajando _________________ status = ${it.state}  ----RESULT = :::::  $dataInfo")
                }
            }
        })
```

It only shows the result of setProgress(workDataOf( ... )) when the process is finished and when it is in execution state null

```
Logs in Activity
30530-30530 ffsss                   cl.smu.unimarcapp.debug              I  trabajando _________________ status = RUNNING  ----RESULT = :::::  null
30530-30530 ffsss                   cl.smu.unimarcapp.debug              I  trabajando _________________ status = RUNNING  ----RESULT = :::::  null
30530-30530 ffsss                   cl.smu.unimarcapp.debug              I  trabajando _________________ status = RUNNING  ----RESULT = :::::  null
30530-30530 ffsss                   cl.smu.unimarcapp.debug              I  isFinished : status =  SUCCEEDED ----RESULT = :::::  MI HORA FINAL = 04/20/2023 09:40:47
```